# Shorten command with variable

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using the following command really often (the real path is longer):

```
>>/root/error.log 2>&1 >>/root/out.log
```

but now I'm trying to shorten it like that:

```
log="$(>>/root/error.log 2>&1 >>/root/out.log)"
```

But when I use the variable in another file, it doesnt work at all:

```
apt-get update -y ${log}
```

Do you have any idea, how to get this working?

**Edit:**
At the moment the command looks like this:

```
apt-get update -y >>/root/error.log 2>&1 >>/root/out.log
```

or

```
apt-get install openssl >>/root/error.log 2>&1 >>/root/out.log
```

... and is working fine. But i want a shorter version for it like:

```
apt-get update -y ${log}
```

or

```
apt-get install openssl ${log}
```

for example

Comment: What are you writing from? You don't appear to have a command? Or are you trying to save the redirections to a variable, because you can't do that. You can save the path and use a variable, but your gonna have to write the redirections as they are performed before variable expansion.

Comment: Have you tried to define an alias?

Comment: @Badacadabra That also wouldn't work

Comment: I edited the main post with the explanation, of what im trying to do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to encapsulate is NOT a command.  It is the redirection portion of a command you want to execute.

This will not work.  You can have file names from variables in redirections, but not the `>`, `>>` or `&1` parts.

The simplest solution is to create a function.

```
execute_and_log()
{
  "$@" >>/root/out.log 2>>/root/error.log
}

execute_and_log any_command with args
```

Note that `"$@"` (the double quotes are very important here) expands to a list of all positional arguments in the current context (which could be no argument at all, which would expand to nothing), each argument being protected from further word splitting, as if called as `"$1" "$2" ...`

Please note that `eval` can be used to execute a command after performing expansions on it, but while it can be used properly, it is tricky and should be seen as a last resort, as there often are simpler and less error-prone solutions.

Another possibility is this :

```
main_log="long/path/to/file1"
err_log="long/path/to/file2"
apt-get update -y >>"$main_log" 2>>"$err_log"
```

Comment: I edited the main post with the explanation, of what im trying to do :)

Comment: What you are trying to do cannot be achieved in the way you are hoping it can.  Do not try putting the redirection symbols inside the variable, it will not work, unless you use `eval` which I would recommend against for this purpose.

Comment: `main_log="long/path/to/file1"
err_log="long/path/to/file2"
apt-get update -y >>"$main_log" 2>>"$err_log"`

Is a good solution for me, thanks!
So all output will be stored to the main.log and all errors to the error.log?

Comment: @Aeris Yes, this is what should happen.  Use `>` instead of `>>` if you want to overwrite the log each time you execute the command instead of appending to it.